# When user click the login button on the home page a session starts and the user is redirect to the same homepage with the form now gone

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller

this is a .net core MVC app and I want that when a user enters his/her identity card number on the homepage then they are redirected to the same page without the form this time and a session is also created against that identity card number.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vW5R.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should add an if on the form with some methods in your controller in order to control if session is saved or not.
something like :
IsUserConnected and use an ng-if=IsUserConnected" in the top of your form declaration.